# Did Fantasy Island have a spinoff aimed at children?

Tags: spin-off, fantasy-island

According to [the TV Tropes page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/FantasyIsland) for *Fantasy Island*, the 1977–84 version of the show had a spinoff aimed at children.

> Spin-Off: For a few weeks ABC tried a Children's version of "Fantasy Island" aired in the 'Family Hour' of Sunday @ 7pm Est time slot. The only differences between it and the 'Saturday @ 10pm' version were that kids had requested the fantasies, and they arrived and departed via Hot Air balloon instead of De Plane. These episodes were syndicated with the parent show.

However, I can't find anything to corroborate that this show actually existed. [The Wikipedia page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/FantasyIsland) for the show doesn't mention a spinoff, nor do the episode descriptions seem to imply that any were aimed at children.

Is there any proof that *Fantasy Island* had a spinoff aimed at children? Or is this something that an imaginative TV Troper invented?

Comment: Ohhhh...interesting!  I remember hearing about this, too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any proof that Fantasy Island had a spinoff aimed at children? Or is this something that an imaginative TV Troper invented?

### The TV Troper's claims are true.

*Fantasy Island* normally [aired on Saturday nights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978%E2%80%9379_United_States_network_television_schedule#Saturday), just after *Love Boat*. Towards the end of [season two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fantasy_Island_episodes#Season_2:_1978%E2%80%9379) though, there are two additional episodes that aired on Sunday, and were titled as, "Sunday specials".

Those two episodes are:

- ["Amusement Park" / "Rock Stars"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0577703/) - May 6, 1979
- ["Cornelius and Alphonse/The Choice"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0577718/) - May 13, 1979

When watching these two episodes, the guests do arrive and depart on hot air balloon, and the shows do involve kid fantasies.

[image]

Comment: So the claim is correct, but a bit misleading. It wasn't a "spinoff show", but more of a backdoor pilot where two episodes had a different tone and were aired at a different time.